# Used attribute of class inside another method of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class Laby that provide a list of tuple (self.paths) and I have a class item that create items.

I am building a method where the items are place randomly using random.sample, I want to use the list from my laby class instead of the attribute my_list from my set_position method.

**This is my laby :**

```
class Laby:

    def __init__(self):

        self.paths = [] # it received some data from another function.. inside a list is created of tuples
```

**This is my Item Class**

```
 class Item:

 # add item to path / randomize pos / 
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.position = (0,0)

    def set_position(self):
        my_liste = [(0, 1),(2,4),(4,2),]  #instead of my list I want to use the path attribute from Laby
        self.position = random.sample(my_liste, 1)


item1 = Item('Object')
item1.set_position()
print('Random pos: ', item1.position , 'Name: ',item1.title)
```

Comment: set_position could take an **instance** of Laby as parameter and take the list from it.

Comment: so something like my_liste = laby ? And set_position will take laby as parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, This is what you want or not?

If I'm wrong, help me to find it out in comments.

You can pass a `Loby` instance to the `set_position` method. **(If this method can accept parameters)**

```py
import random


class Laby:

    def __init__(self):
        self.paths = []

    def set_paths(self, paths):
        self.paths = paths

    def get_paths(self):
        return self.paths


class Item:

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.position = (0, 0)

    def set_position(self, laby):
        my_liste = laby.get_paths()
        self.position = random.sample(my_liste, 1)


paths = [(0, 1), (2, 4), (4, 2), ]

# initialize laby
laby1 = Laby()
laby1.set_paths(paths)

item1 = Item('Object')
item1.set_position(laby1)
print('Random pos: ', item1.position, 'Name: ', item1.title)
```

**Output:**

```
Random pos:  [(2, 4)] Name:  Object
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your problem i am presenting below code:

```
import random

class Laby(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.paths = [(0, 1),(2,4),(4,2)]

class Item(Laby):
 # add item to path / randomize pos /
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.position = (0,0)

    def set_position(self):
        super(Item, self).__init__()
        self.position = random.sample(self.paths, 1)


item1 = Item('Object')
item1.set_position()
print('Random pos: ', item1.position , 'Name: ',item1.title)
```